# 'Close' Button That Won't Close Popup For a Minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup that automatically loads, it has a close button, a print button, and some content along with a background image. I also have set it up so that when the key 'g' is pressed the popup reappears. Now, what I have been trying to do, to little avail, is add a timer to the close button so that the popup can't be closed for 1 minute after the popup has appeared. I have found the following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/) but I am not sure how to implement it into my code. My code is displayed below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
             $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible"); 
             $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1); 
        }
    });
    $(function(){
  
       $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible"); 
       $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1); 
  
       });
  
  $( ".close" ).click(function() {

       $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
       $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
});

        function printDiv()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('printableDiv').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
            win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
        }
```

```css
    .t {
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        -moz-transform-origin: top left;
        -o-transform-origin: top left;
        -ms-transform-origin: top left;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
        -o-transform: scale(0.25);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        white-space: pre;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    #t1_1{left:256px;top:35px;letter-spacing:0.1px;}
    #t2_1{left:334px;top:87px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t3_1{left:210px;top:123px;}
    #t4_1{left:238px;top:123px;word-spacing:-0.3px;}
    #t5_1{left:210px;top:141px;}
    #t6_1{left:210px;top:160px;}
    #t7_1{left:210px;top:179px;}
    #t8_1{left:238px;top:141px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t9_1{left:238px;top:160px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ta_1{left:238px;top:179px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tb_1{left:343px;top:242px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tc_1{left:210px;top:278px;}
    #td_1{left:210px;top:297px;}
    #te_1{left:210px;top:315px;}
    #tf_1{left:210px;top:334px;}
    #tg_1{left:238px;top:278px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #th_1{left:238px;top:297px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ti_1{left:238px;top:315px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #tj_1{left:238px;top:334px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tk_1{left:286px;top:393px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tl_1{left:210px;top:429px;}
    #tm_1{left:210px;top:448px;}
    #tn_1{left:210px;top:466px;}
    #to_1{left:210px;top:485px;}
    #tp_1{left:238px;top:429px;word-spacing:-0.3px;}
    #tq_1{left:238px;top:448px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tr_1{left:238px;top:466px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #ts_1{left:238px;top:485px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #tt_1{left:326px;top:544px;letter-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #tu_1{left:210px;top:580px;}
    #tv_1{left:210px;top:599px;}
    #tw_1{left:210px;top:618px;}
    #tx_1{left:238px;top:618px;}
    #ty_1{left:210px;top:636px;}
    #tz_1{left:238px;top:636px;}
    #t10_1{left:210px;top:655px;}
    #t11_1{left:238px;top:580px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t12_1{left:238px;top:599px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t13_1{left:238px;top:655px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t14_1{left:264px;top:716px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t15_1{left:210px;top:752px;}
    #t16_1{left:210px;top:771px;}
    #t17_1{left:210px;top:789px;}
    #t18_1{left:210px;top:808px;}
    #t19_1{left:238px;top:752px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t1a_1{left:238px;top:771px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}
    #t1b_1{left:238px;top:789px;word-spacing:-0.2px;}
    #t1c_1{left:238px;top:808px;word-spacing:-0.1px;}

    .s1_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    }

    .s2_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    }

    .s3_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }

    .s4_1{
        FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }

    div {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }

      .button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        border-radius: 20px/50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background: orange;
      }
      .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        transition: opacity 500ms;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        height: 578%;
        width: 117.5%;
      }
      .overlay:target {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        display:none;
      }
      .PopUp {
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 60%;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
      }
      .PopUp .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 30px;
        transition: all 200ms;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
      }
      .PopUp .close:hover {
        color: orange;
      }
      .PopUp .content {
        max-height: 117.5%;
        overflow: auto;
      }

.pdf1 {
width: 935px;
height: 1210px;
background-color: white;
-moz-transform: scale(1);
z-index: 0;
border: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
        <div class="PopUp">
            <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="printableDiv" id="printableDiv"></div>
<div id="p1" class=p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

   <!-- Begin page background -->
<div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img></div>
   <!-- End page background -->


<!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
<div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
<div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
<div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
<div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
<div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
<div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
<div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
<div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
<div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
<div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
<div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
<div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
<div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
<div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
<div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
<div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
<div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
<div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
<div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
<div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
<div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
<div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
<div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
<div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
<div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
<div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
<div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
<div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv()" value="Print">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can disable the button when loading and call a function after one minute (setTimeout) that enables the button.

Comment: 1. That's evil 2. you can probably use setTimeout to add the close button, because having a close button that doesn't work is kinda misleading

Comment: @Brian 1. I intend for this to only occur for new users and for my program I need everyone to be on the same page about the contents of the popup & 2. I kinda want the timer to be displayed so that the user understands that they can't click 'Close' until the time expires.

Comment: A timer on a close button usually indicates that the window is closing itself after the time expires. So you have to be careful how you present that.

Comment: I am going to write a browser plugin for your users so they don't have to wait in order to close that popup. That's evil. If you want to force them into seeing some set of UI elements, a popup is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I modified your code and added this line above the close button:

```
<label id="close-message"></label>
```

Then in your document load function, I added a timeout function similar to the example you linked. In your code, you added an click event listener to close your popup. What I had done was bind that event listener only after the timer is done. That way, even if they click the button nothing happens, as long as it is still counting down. Timer dropped down to 5 seconds for testing.

```
  var counter = 5;
  $("#close-message").html("You can close this in " + counter + " seconds");  
  var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter > 0) {
      $("#close-message").html("You can close this in " + counter + " seconds");
    } else {
      $( ".close" ).click(function() {
        $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
        $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
      });
      $("#close-message").remove();
      clearInterval(setMsg);
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Check out [my bin](https://jsbin.com/riwigosajo/edit?output)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the anchor tag. Maybe something like:

```
<a class="close" id="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
```

Then you could add the following js script:

```
$('#close').css("visibility", "hidden");

setTimeout(function(){
$('#close').css("visibility", "visible"); 
},60000);
```

This will set the visibility of the close link to "hidden" until 1 minute has passed, then it will be set to "visible"

EDIT:

If you want the button visible the whole time, you could use the setTimout() to add the href attr after 1 minute or whatever you need to add to close the popup:

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('#close').attr('href','http://example.com');
},60000);
```

EDIT 2:
If you have this anchor tag:

```
<a id="close"></a>
```

You can add this script to have a count down and then show the close button with the correct href attr that you set with the script:

```
  var num = 5;

  var counter = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('close').innerHTML='Close this popup in '+num+' 
  seconds';
  num--;

if(num < 0){ 
  close_ad();
}

function close_ad(){
  document.getElementById('close').href='http://www.google.com';
  document.getElementById('close').innerHTML='Click Here';
  clearInterval(counter);
}
},1000);
```

Comment: Code did not appear to work. Let me clarify, is this code supposed to prevent you from clicking the 'Close' button until 60 seconds has passed? Or is it supposed to hide the link until 60 seconds has passed? It did not seem to do either of those two.

Comment: The code should cause the close button to not be seen for the first 60 seconds.

Comment: Edit only caused it for the first 60 seconds to go to whatever url I entered and then after that close the popup. What I am trying to do is have a timer shown where the close button is supposed to be and when that timer hits 0 it allows you to close the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set `Timeout()` and `SetInterval()` on close of popup

```
$( ".close" ).click(function() {
    cnt=0;
    $(this).css({opacity:0})
    var interval=setInterval(function(){
    if(cnt<=60){
      ++cnt;
      $("#time_container").css("opacity",1)
      $("#time_container").html("Please wait"+cnt);
      console.log(cnt);
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(interval);
      $("#time_container").css("opacity",0)
    }
  },1000);
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
       $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);


},60000);
```

[click here for demo](https://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/ZKOZvJ)

Comment: The code only starts the timer when the 'Close ' button is clicked, can the timer start when the page is loaded?

Comment: Isn't that what you need  "so that the popup can't be closed for 1 minute after the popup has appeared" ?

Comment: @repzero he wanted a non-functioning button with a message showing how long until the button starts working